# How we modify or add or delete some country name in magento2.x for all store?

Tags: magento2

Using below code in magento2.x I can find out the list of countries with name

```
<?php 
namespace Readymate\Samplemodule\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_countryCollectionFactory;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
            $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
        }

        public function getCountryCollection()
        {
            $collection = $this->_countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore();
            return $collection;
        }

        public function getCountries()
        {
            return $options = $this->getCountryCollection()
                        ->toOptionArray();
        }
}
```

But, I want to know where **magento2.x stores all country name** for "Locale- English (United States)"? Because, I want to modify some country names e.g "Macau SAR China" to "Macau" and want to delete some country from list.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all tables related countries from where you can remove country, states and rename country and states as well.

directory_country

directory_country_region

directory_country_region_name

directory_currency_rate